# Нужна ли запятая в коротком предложении "Узнать что изменилось"?

Tags: пунктуация

Непонятно, по какому правилу стоит ставить запятую и стоит ставить ли ее вообще.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Узнать, что изменилось.**

Это сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным изъяснительным и  союзным словом ЧТО, запятая ставится между главной и придаточной частью, в устной речи делается пауза.

**Запятая не ставится** перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом в **составе неразложимых сочетаний.**

Например: **бери что хочешь** (= любую вещь). Нет паузы и запятой.

Розенталь http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/50.htm